# org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I am making a web service. İt will return to Twitter profile photo's url which given username.

When i just return text there aren't any problem. When i added my code it give me error which on uploaded photo.

I think my code have missises. Please help me.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.IOException;

@Path("/url_processes")
public class Url_Processes {
    @GET

    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String get_url(String username)
    {
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://twitter.com/" + username).get();
            Elements tags = doc.select("img[class]");
            if (tags.isEmpty() != true) {
                for (Element tag : tags) {
                    String class_name = tag.attr("class");
                    if (class_name == "ProfileAvatar-image") {
                        return tag.select("href").toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Photo can not fund. Please check username";
    }
}
```

[[İMAGE] Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEwIz.png)

**HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error**

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
root cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0 logs.
```

Comment: It means Jsoup is not available on your server classpath. Which server are you using and how do you deploy your app?

Comment: i used these steps

1. Click File from the toolbar.
2.Project Structure ( CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X)
3. Select Modules at the left panel.
4. Dependencies tab.
5. '+' → JARs or directories.

Comment: studio is Intellij IDEA on windows

Comment: Are Jsoup available in your jar?

Comment: yes it's avaible, when i remove from project. Ide gives error about Jsoup

Comment: That’s not what I meant. I meant does jsoup jar present in your jar when you unzip it. Look in the web-inf/lib

Comment: Sorry i dont understand  here is project files .. http://i68.tinypic.com/dlp0jp.png

http://i64.tinypic.com/k9yk5f.png

Comment: You project should produce a jar or a war to be deployed in  your glassfish server. You have to find it and check if the jsoup lib is exported properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am thinking i can not fix it, so i am going to use anouther parser lib.

Comment: As you want but I used Soup before and I am pretty sure the lib is fine. Good luck anyway